# Class not found error in Java when using an enum

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I have the following code:

```
enum CarEnum {
   BMW("BMW"), TOYOTA("Toyota"), FORD("Ford");
   String name;
   CarEnum(String s) {
      name = s;
   }
}
class Cars {
   static CarEnum a;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(a.BMW.name + " " + a.FORD.name);
   }
}
```

It's in a file named Cars.java

When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Car
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Car
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Why is it saying the class Car is not found?

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole code ? I see no mention of a `Car` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ Your code is working I copy/paste it right away

2/ You mention a `Car` class in your Exception but non are present in your code

3/ Are you certain to launch the good class main method ?

Comment: I am not sure what happened. In the eclipse explorer I could see no mention of other files. I started a new project and fresh code and it worked. Thanks for checking for me.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
public class Cars {
   enum CarEnum {
       BMW("BMW"), TOYOTA("Toyota"), FORD("Ford");
       String name;
       CarEnum(String s) {
          name = s;
       }
   }
   static CarEnum a = CarEnum.BMW;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //you never initialized your a so you can print
      System.out.println(a.name);
      //or to check all your Enums Names
      System.out.println(CarEnum.BMW.name + " " + CarEnum.Ford.name);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the only problem is that when you have run your code you gave the command `java Car` instead of `java Cars`.

Answer (score 1):

Please recheck the File name. Because the error references `Car` which is not available in the code. Try to rename the file as `Cars.java`.